Is it possible to make a cylinder (snake) move along a path using its rig system?
I have created a worm-like mesh from a cylinder and some bendy bones. Is it possible for me to define a path that the cylinder should travel? It's traveling through the path would be possible because of the rig it has (?)


In that case maybe the simplest way to do it would be not to use an armature but to make the mesh follow a curve with the help of a Curve modifier?

To support @moonboots comment, may this help you: Animate object along path and deform accordingly ?
